# HP Recovery options: System Recovery not showing

Tags: hp-pavilion

I am using HP Pavilion dv4 notebook. Previously, there were following options in Recovery Manager(using f11 during boot):

+System Recovery
+Factory Restore
+Minimized Image Recovery

The **System Recovery** option allows me to restore only Operating system drive e.g. C:\ drive, keeping all other user (me) created hard drives intact. **I made a set of recovery disk**. Since then I don't see the **System Recovery** option in HP Recovery Manager. But all other options are still there. But when I use recovery disks that i created earlier, that option e.g. System Recovery is shown. But It's really boring and time consuming to use disks for recovery. So, what's the problem with internal HP Recovery Manager? Why isn't it showing that option?

Comment: Unsure if this'll be helpful to you, but maybe: http://www.ehow.com/how_7342895_use-hp-recovery-manager.html

Comment: Sorry, It's not supposed to make sense